# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Laravel forbidden for file get

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i'm deploying laravel inside an aws elastic beanstalk and I have set the database and the project with success and for avoid using storage:link and the kind i'm using a route to get the files(an image, i.e.) . 
like this:

```
Route::get('storage/{folder}/{filename}', function ($folder,$filename)
{
    // Add folder path here instead of storing in the database.
    $path = storage_path('app/public/'.$folder.'/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

So... i have 2 diferent projects with the same base configs in laravel (app.php, database.php, .env , etc) , and the same enviroment and app config in aws, but in one im getting the image access and in the other im getting

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /storage/productos/pruebalibro.pdf on this server.
```

some though? what can i check or do? i know that aws creates stuff in ec2 and other stuff but what should i look into?

Comment: are you using S3. if soo check your bucket permissions

Comment: not intentionally, maybe is an offshoot of using Beanstalk, but i'll check it to see if it's the problem

Comment: I had a similar issue, solved it by having a post-deploy script on this folder: .platform/hooks/postdeploy with the following code: sudo chmod -Rf 0777 storage/*